# Relative pronoun "in which" vs. relative adverb "where" II

Tags: relative-clauses, mathematics

I am confused by why the following sentence is connected with "in which".

> The term "applied mathematics" also describes the professional specialty *in which* mathematicians work on practical problems by formulating and studying mathematical models.

Why this sentence can be  connected by using "in which"?

Also I learned that "[preposition] + [which]" can be substituted by relative adverbs. For example, "This is a house in which I live" is equal to "This is a house where I live". The sentence can be divided into "This is a house" & "I live in the house.", and it is easy to concatenate with relative clauses.

So adding to the question, can *in which* be replaced with "where"?

If you are familiar with mathematics, I also ask that if "We define the function f by f(x)=ax+b, *where* a and b are constants." can be substituted by *in which*?

Comment: In many instances "in which" and "where" are in competition. "Where" functions as a locative adjunct, though it may be less likely to suggest location. A double-variant representation of "This is the house where I live" is "This is house x; I live in x". The "in" component is contributed by "where" together with its spatial location function.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for commenting. So in that quoted case, 'in which' does not suggest location, or spatial location, thus 'where' is inappropriate to use. Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps the (very) old-fashioned 'This is the house wherein I live' better brings out the similarity. With 'this is', coordinate location hardly needs further specification (unless perhaps you're looking at a map).

Comment: No: a locative expression as antecedent is not obligatory. There may be situations where the head noun does not suggest location, cf. "I don't want to find myself in a position where I can't win" / "This is the web page where the claim was first made".